# date in pig latin

Tags: date, input, apache-pig

I am trying to do the following. I have multiple dates and I want to create a pig script which gets unknown number of input dates and then runs the pig script for the input arguments. My question is:

How can I send an unknown number of input variables to a pig script and then handle them within the pig script?

Thanks
Sara

Comment: igpay atinlay siay oolcay!!

Answer (score 0):

> I have some trouble understanding what you actually want to do. That would be my solution >for your problem, sending an unknown number of dates (sorted as chararray):
>
> ```
> A = load 'input_dates' AS (date:chararray);
> B = my_macro(A);
> ```
>
> It's quite basic, so I guess I didn't understand your problem correctly. Could you maybe >develop a little bit more your problem?

***UPDATE*** >> How about something like this **if you use Pig 0.11** ([there is a bug until 0.10 for module imports](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2665)):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

from org.apache.pig.scripting import *

P = Pig.compile("""
data = LOAD '$docs_in' AS (a:int);
-- do something
""")

lof = os.listdir("/home/.../dates/")
params = []

for elem in lof:
    params.append({'docs_in': str(elem)})
    lof.remove(elem)

bound = P.bind(list_of_files)
stats = bound.run(params)
```

If each run is counting on the result of the previous one, use `runSingle()` instead.

Comment: Actually I want to load the contents of multiple files: like 20120301 20120302 20120304

Answer (score -1):

If I understand question correctly, you want to load number of files or directories. You can specify as "," as input.
Below is an example:

load.pig (content):

```
A = LOAD '$input' using PigStorage();
dump A;
```

command to run ( to run locally):

```
pig -x local -param input=20120301,20120302,20120304 load.pig
```